# How can I convert a list of zipped packages to a local CRAN repo?

Tags: r

I work on a server that doesn't have Internet access and I just have a local folder that contains all CRAN packages as zipped folders (for example there's `dplyr_1.0.9.zip` that contains a folder `dplyr` that contains `doc`, `help`, `Meta`, `MD5`, etc.). There are about 18,000 zipped folders.

I can install each package independently with:

```r
install.packages(<path_to_zipped_pkg>, repos = NULL, type = "binary")
```

but it doesn't automatically install dependencies so I would need to figure them out for all the packages I want to install and install them manually. I'm wondering whether this list of zipped folders can't be converted to a CRAN-like repository that would allow automatic installation of dependencies.

I tried to follow [this `packrat` tutorial](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/custom-repos.html) but I'm a bit stuck on how I can convert this list of zipped folders in a proper CRAN-like repo. Here's what I did so far:

```r
localCRAN <- path.expand("~/local-cran")
dir.create(localCRAN)
contribDir <- file.path(localCRAN, "src", "contrib")
dir.create(contribDir, recursive = TRUE)
dir.create(file.path(localCRAN, "bin/windows.contrib/4.1"), recursive = TRUE)
```

Any insights on what I should do next? Do I need to unzip all 18,000+ zipped folders and put them in "bin/windows.contrib/4.1"?

Comment: ‘packrat’ is deprecated and has been replaced by ‘renv’. But neither of them (to the best of my knowledge, despite the article you linked) manage *repositories*. You’d want ‘miniCRAN’ for that. If you want to create the repository manually you can follow the instructions from your link but you’d need to manually download and copy *all* transitive dependnecies of ‘dplyr’, which is rather a chore (and I’m not sure that the macOS instructions are still up to date).

Comment: I saw this package but its vignette uses the URL `CRAN = "http://cran.microsoft.com"`, which I can't use (no Internet access). So the rest of the vignette is a bit hard to adapt without being able to run the first lines

Comment: You should be able to replace this with any other CRAN mirror. E.g. `https://cloud.r-project.org/`.

Comment: The problem is not the URL, it's the fact I don't have internet access on the server where I want this local CRAN

Comment: Well obviously to *create* the repo you need access to the internet to download the packages. Run the code to create the repository on a computer with internet connection, and then copy the created repository to the system without internet connection.

Comment: But I have all the packages on the server without internet access. Each of them is a zipped folder (see the beginning of the post)

Comment: Well if you insist on using this zipped folder then the answer to your initial question is “yes”: you need to extract all those ZIP files manually and put the contents into the appropriate location, in the appropriate format, in a manually created folder structure for your local repository. The point of using ‘miniCRAN’ is that this is rather a lot of work which can be automated. But “a folder full of ZIP files” isn’t the common way in which R packages are stored, which is why ‘miniCRAN’ doesn’t support it (nor any other package, to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: Both `miniCRAN` and `drat` are designed to provided local CRAN-alike repos for use by `install.packages`.  Creating the `PACKAGES` etc file is just one call to an R helper, but there is more -- which is why (at least) two helper packages exist and are used.

Comment: So in the end I'm a bit confused. I get that I can't use `miniCRAN` in this setting, but should it be fine to extract all zipped files in "~/local-cran/bin/windows.contrib/4.1"?

Comment: No, you shouldn’t unpack the packages. For Windows binary packages, the the ZIP file is already the format that is expected from a CRAN-like repository. However, as Dirk mentioned you’ll also have to create the `PACKAGES` file.

Comment: Ok, I never heard of this file. Can you point me to some reference on this?

Comment: @bretauv *The link you’ve posted* describes the file and describes how to create it.

Comment: ah great, I didn't notice. Thank you